# How can I make a regular expression match upper and lower case?

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't really know much about regex at all, but if someone could help me change the following code to also allow for lowercase a-z, that would be great!

```
$("input.code").keyup(function(){
    this.value = this.value.match(/[A-Z]{3}([0-9]{1,4})?|[A-Z]{1,3}/)[0];
});
```

Comment: You mean like with `/i`?

Comment: What are you trying to match? Your regex looks wrong.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you want a regular expression to be case-insensitive, add a `i` [modifier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) to the end of the regex.  Like so:

```
/[A-Z]{3}([0-9]{1,4})?|[A-Z]{1,3}/i
```

Answer (score 12):

```
/[A-Za-z]{3}([0-9]{1,4})?|[A-Za-z]{1,3}/
```

`[]` denotes a character class and `A-Z` is a allowed range and means ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. You can extend this easy by adding `a-z`

Comment: @muntoo probably clashed with my own edit done at the same time adding the other 3 lines.

Comment: -1 For suggesting that `[a-zA-Z]` is equivalent to `\w`. And why are you using `[\w]{3}` instead of just `\w{3}`?

Comment: `\w` allows more than `[a-zA-Z]` - as [Regex Cheat Sheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html), says it matches in 'Most engines: "word character": ASCII letter, digit or underscore'. Other references are also available....