# simple regex for street address

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I know there are a dozen questions at least on this. I am trying to have a simple validation of input for street address using Regex whereby I check for at least two spaces in the input entry. The reason? for the most part us addresses are at least 3 parts, street number, street name, type (lane, drive, ave , st ,etc)

I want to alert the user if the entry doesn't match at least that, if it has more than three spaces, meaning it has more names in the address, that's fine but the minimum not being met necessitates an alert. My latest effort is below, and is not working.

```
  var addregex = new RegExp("^\d{1,6}\040([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,}\040[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,})$|^\d{1,6}\040([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,}\040[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,}\040[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,})$|^\d{1,6}\040([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,}\040[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,}\040[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,}\040[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,})$");

            if (addregex.test($(this).val())) {
                alert('is valid');
                address.addClass('isvalid');
                address.css("border", "1px solid lightgray");
            } else {
                address.css("border", "2px solid red");
                alert("Are you sure this is a valid street address?");
                address.focus();
            }
```

Comment: Not sure I get it, is that huge regex just to check for two spaces?

Comment: I would just count spaces (trim, compare length to length with \s replaced) - not all addresses begin with numbers.

Comment: ^^^`str.split(/\s+/g).length > 2`

Comment: I tried that using split(" ") which apparently doesn't work as well as your regex version which seems to work

Comment: US street addresses can contain number + street only.

Comment: Addresses are not regular, and regex should not be used to validate them unless you are comfortable with missing a *lot* of cases (sometimes 20% to 40%). Here is a useful article about addresses and regex: https://smartystreets.com/articles/regular-expressions-for-street-addresses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple test is all you need:    `/^\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){2}/`

Comment: This misses several address styles, such as "123 West 2nd Ave"

Comment: this literally matches any string

Answer (score 8):

`\w+(\s\w+){2,}`

Description:

- `\w+` => Alphanumeric, one or more repititions
- `\s` => Whitespace
- `(\s\w+)` => A numbered capture group [\s\w+]
- `{2,}` => at least 2 repititions

Answer (score 3):

I could not get the other guys to work for some reason but this one validates all street addresses I have ever come up with...

```
var value = '12136 Test This Road';
var streetAddRegEx = new RegExp('/\d{1,}(\s{1}\w{1,})(\s{1}?\w{1,})+)/g');
console.log(streetAddRegEx.test(value));
```

Basically I made it so it was any set of words more then one proceeding a set of numbers...

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //d{1,}(s{1}w{1,})(s{1}?w{1,})+)/g/: Unmatched ')'
    at RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:2:22

Comment: This does not work for PO Boxes such as "PO Box 123"

Comment: this is the best regex for address i've found on the internet

Answer (score 1):

You've got some viable suggestion here. I would however like to offer you a regex that I think does what you asked for:

```
\d+\s+\w+\s+\w+
```

or, if it's a warning only, you could even add testing of "types" you indicated, like:

```
\d+\s+\w+\s+(?:st(?:\.|reet)?|ave(?:\.|nue)?|lane|dr(?:\.|ive)?)
```

allowing for abbreviated version with or without full stop. (Add road, court, etc. at will)

Check it out at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lA7sT4).

Hope this helps,

Regards

EDIT: Remember to add flag for case insensitive. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Improved version based on ClasG's answer.

```
/\d+(\s+\w+){1,}\s+(?:st(?:\.|reet)?|dr(?:\.|ive)?|pl(?:\.|ace)?|ave(?:\.|nue)?|rd|road|lane|drive|way|court|plaza|square|run|parkway|point|pike|square|driveway|trace|park|terrace|blvd)/
```

Comment: This only works after you convert the address to lower case. 
To fix you can add the UPPER case characters (like this `...|[Rr][Dd]|...` for Rd). Or you can use the [\i modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7411206/7988857)

Comment: See an updated version here [https://regex101.com/r/pT8vX9/1](https://regex101.com/r/pT8vX9/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!\s*$)^((?!([p|P][-. ]?[o|O].?[- ]?|post office )[b|B]([ox|OX]))(?!(\`|\~|\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\[|\{|\]|\}|\||\\|\'|\<|\,|\.|\>|\?|\"|\;|\:)).)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

`^(?:[A-Za-z]+[ -]?)+[A-Za-z]$`

Street only. Letters, single dash/space repeated but not ending with dash/space