# Regex: Match only street name within address

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have a list of addresses and I would like to have a regular expression that is able to capture just the name of the street without the street type, address number, or cardinal direction. There are some errors in formatting but all characters are in capital letters. So,

```
2038 W MAIN AVE
2038QWEW S JEFFERSON AVENUE
33 NORTH CALIFORNIA STREET
53371 SOUTH WASHINGTON
53371 S WASHINGTON AVENUE
1600 E PENNSYLVANIA AVE
WEST9 67ST ST
E171 N 23RD STREET
G171 N121ST STREET
```

ought to return

```
MAIN
JEFFERSON
CALIFORNIA
WASHINGTON
WASHINGTON
PENNSYLVANIA
67ST
23RD
121ST
```

So far I've got

```
([^ W ]|[^ E ]|[^ S ]|[^ N ])([0-9])*([A-Z]+)[^ ]
```

But I can't seem to only capture the first match that occurs after the street number. I feel like I need the standard greedy operators (i.e. `?`, `*`, or `+`) but I can't figure out how to incorporate them.

These two links have taken me close:

[Matching on every second occurence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589667/match-at-every-second-occurrence)

[Simple regex for street address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264194/simple-regex-for-street-address)

Comment: What language or tool are you doing this in? It looks like you're just trying to extract the second-to-last string from each line. Are there exceptions to that in your data?

Comment: Is your fourth address ok? Or is `53371 SOUTH WASHINGTON STREET` correct?

Comment: There are generally no exceptions but, for example this is not the case in the fourth address above where the street name is the final option. If there is a way to do this without that one outlier that is okay. I am using a combination of Python and R.

Comment: Try `(?im)\b(?:(?:WEST|NORTH|EAST|SOUTH)\d*|(?!^)[NEWS](?![a-z])) *(\S+)` What you need is in first capturing group. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/IVOUnf/1

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for your help.

Comment: that's some scarily naive assumptions about street names you're making there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out in a slightly different way

```
[0-9A-Z]* [0-9A-Z]*$
```

and then I simply split the string it created by the space. Maybe one or two steps too many but it's transparent

Answer (score 1):

For the output what you want from the given (address) input, this regex will surely help: **[\pL\pN]+(?=\h+[\pL\pN]+$)**

This regex will **match the second last word** in your line where a word is "1 or more any letter or digit in any language".

For reference you could https://superuser.com/questions/1361759/matching-second-last-word-in-sentence-through-regular-expression

Answer (score 0):

Logic: we are looking for the second last word (set of characters) + possible border with the symbol N

```
^.*?\s[N]{0,1}([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*\w*$
```

Res:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-15    `2038 W MAIN AVE`
Group 1.    7-11    `MAIN`
Match 2
Full match  16-43   `2038QWEW S JEFFERSON AVENUE`
Group 1.    27-36   `JEFFERSON`
Match 3
Full match  44-70   `33 NORTH CALIFORNIA STREET`
Group 1.    53-63   `CALIFORNIA`
Match 4
Full match  71-93   `53371 SOUTH WASHINGTON`
Group 1.    83-93   `WASHINGTON`
Match 5
Full match  94-119  `53371 S WASHINGTON AVENUE`
Group 1.    102-112 `WASHINGTON`
Match 6
Full match  120-143 `1600 E PENNSYLVANIA AVE`
Group 1.    127-139 `PENNSYLVANIA`
Match 7
Full match  144-157 `WEST9 67ST ST`
Group 1.    150-154 `67ST`
Match 8
Full match  158-176 `E171 N 23RD STREET`
Group 1.    165-169 `23RD`
Match 9
Full match  177-195 `G171 N121ST STREET`
Group 1.    183-188 `121ST`
```

https://regex101.com/r/m2rmUQ/4

Comment: Please see the fourth match returned by your regex. It's `SOUTH`.

Comment: You're potentially filtering out `SQUARE` or `ALLEY` or `BLVD` or other suffixes and you enclosed those suffixes in brackets. It should be parentheses.

Comment: ok)) here unversal expression. Updated my answer . `^.*?\s[N]{0,1}([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*\w*$`

Comment: It doesn't capture `121ST` in `W121ST`.